# HQL where clause 'greater than' with jadira PersistentDateTimeWithZone

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I'm using jadira PersistentDateTimeWithZone to store a joda DateTime with timezone. It all works as expected, except for searching for dates using ">=" - it compares the time timezone string in the where clause (see SQL at bottom).  Is there any way to further refine my annotaion or HQL to prevent this, or is it a bug in Jadira

```
   @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
   @Columns(columns={@Column(name="departureDate", nullable = false),@Column(name="departureDateTimezone", nullable = false)})
   private DateTime depScheduled;
```

My HQL query in my JpaRepository:

```
   /** 
    * Get all things that depart after the given date
    */  
   @Query("select e from MyTable e where depScheduled>=?1")
   List<MyTable> loadDatFromMyTable(DateTime depDate);
```

The generated SQL - see it is trying to compare both the date and the timezone string (:

```
   Hibernate: 
       select
           x.departureDate as departur5_4_,
           x.departureDateTimezone as departur6_4_,    
       from
           MyTable x 
       where
           and crewroster0_.departureDate>=? 
           and crewroster0_.departureDateTimezone>=?
```

Comment: could you comment if one of the answers was helpful in your case?

Comment: Neither helped. In the end I dropped the composite org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone and used just org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime.  To set my expected time zone, I used a @PostLoad method to modify the DateTime value read from the database.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer so I can award the bounty on it?

Answer (score 1):

The type is actually a Hibernate CompositeType (like all of the Jadira multicolumn types). This lets you query on the components of the type. For this type the two components are: 'datetime' and 'offset', therefore, try referring to the component within the type as depScheduled.datetime.

There is a good discussion of CompositeTypes at: http://learningviacode.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/creating-hibernate-custom-type-2.html

Comment: Could you add an Example how Kevin should change his Query to match his needs?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get either solution working. So I left my column as a DateType and set the timezone required after loading the data. In my case, I calculate the timezone from the city.

```
 @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
 private LocalDate myDateTime;

 @Column(type="String")
 private String city;

 @PostLoad
 public void postLoad() {
    DateTimeZone = getTimeZoneFrom(this.city);
    MutableDateTime mdt = new MutableDateTime(this.myDateTime);
    mdt.setZone(dateTimeZone);
    this.myDateTime = mdt.toDateTime();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you .setDate() for that hql query?

because you must enter the date as a object, not as a string in native query.

can you try something like:

```
Date x = //your date
String hql = "from MyTable e where depScheduled>=:givenDate";

List<MyTable> myTable = yourSession.createQuery(hql).setDate("givenDate", x).list();
```